# Java Image loading can't find one image

Tags: java, image

I have that I cannot load a single image (out of many) outside of IDE. I' m using `ImageLoader`:

```
private Image loadImageFile(String path){
    System.out.println("Load image: "+path);
    URL imgPath = getClass().getResource(path);          
    Image img = null;

    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(imgPath);
    } 
    catch(IllegalArgumentException | IOException e){
        System.out.println("Cannot find file.");
    }
    return img;
}
```

All my paths that are passed down to that function starts with "/". As is shown in outputs. Here is output from Netbeans:

```
Load image: /res/uvodBG.png
...
Load image: /res/userBG.png
Load image: /res/ruletaTopBG.jpg
...
Load image: /res/uvodRegBG.png
```

Everything runs fine under Netbeans but when I try to run .jar file:

```
Load image: /res/uvodBG.png
...
Load image: /res/userBG.png
Cannot find file.
Load image: /res/ruletaTopBG.jpg
...
Load image: /res/uvodRegBG.png
```

---

So my question is, why, when running it from .jar file, not all but only ONE image isn't loaded properly.

---

StackTrace:

```
Lis 17, 2014 11:58:51 DOP. loader.ImageLoader loadImageFile
SEVERE: null
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1388)
at loader.ImageLoader.loadImageFile(ImageLoader.java:40)
at loader.ImageLoader.loadTexture(ImageLoader.java:31)
at viewParts.inner.UserInfoPanel.<init>(UserInfoPanel.java:66)
at viewParts.inner.RoomsInnerPanel.<init>(RoomsInnerPanel.java:82)
at viewParts.inner.LoginInnerPanel.<init>(LoginInnerPanel.java:80)
at viewParts.RuletteFrame.<init>(RuletteFrame.java:38)
at starter.NURRulette.main(NURRulette.java:20)
```

And at UserInfoPanel.java:66 is:

```
background = loader.loadTexture(BACKGROUND_PATH);
```

where I call the loader instance in constructor with BACKGROUND_PATH being private final String BACKGROUND_PATH = "/res/userBG.png";  in the same class.

---

MANIFEST file

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.2
Created-By: 1.8.0_05-b13 (Oracle Corporation)
Class-Path: 
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: starter.NURRulette
```

Structure of jar file

- actionPerformers
- appRenderThread
- ...
- loader
- META-INF
- res
- ...

All images, including userBG.png, are in the `res` folder.
The `ImageLoader.class` file is in the `loader` folder.

Comment: Does the image exist in the Jar?  Has the image been corrupted during the build process?  Is it an old/out-of-date Jar?

Comment: It would be more helpful if in the `catch` block you actually displayed the class of the exception and its message, at least while you're debugging.

Comment: Could you print the error stack trace, and add it to your question. It helps to see the error stack trace.

Comment: @RealSkeptic sure it points to where i call the loader with final String path as parameter.

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes it does exist in jar and can be normally opened so not corrupted, and the jar is the same application so it is builded every time

Comment: Can you try replacing the call `getClass().getResource(path)` with `getClass.getClassLoader().getResource(path)`?

Comment: @RealSkeptic sure i can, but in that case i need to remove the leading "/" in all paths, but the problem is same (runs fine in IDE but not with .jar) and the same image isnt loaded

Comment: The IDE has a different class loader than Java. There is probably some subtle difference in the images. Can you show a listing of the jar (showing the loader and the images at least)? What's in the manifest?

Comment: @jiraspav try to change the extension of the img to png no matter if it is a jpg image file just try